# looking for a simple realistic parametric volatility model

Tags: volatility, implied-volatility, models, local-volatility

Which parametric volatility is realistic to test quickly and qualitatively a model?
I do not wish to fit market quotes but would like to have a non-trivial volatility with skew or smile to do some MC simulation.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand this line: *"Which parametric volatility is realistic to test quickly and qualitatively a model?"* So basically you want to settle on a model and then test the model qualitatively? What should this *"qualitatively test"* include? Also, whether a model is realistic depends a lot things for instance asset class. I am not sure what you mean wit realistic.

You mention MC and smile. You can go for a stochastic(Heston/sabr) or local model, choose arbitrary parameters, implement MC simulation (requires discrimination) and use the simulation to create the smile/prices.

Comment: I am voting to close this question because it is unclear what you are asking about. Please edit and add more about what the purpose of your experiments is.

Comment: eg for illiquid underlyings, we need to build an implied vol and it's companion local vol, at least statiscally non-arbitrageable.